# Mythological basis for WoT main characters?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

I was thinking the other day about how Mat echoes elements of Norse mythology such as Loki (trickster) and Odin (hanging). Rand represents messianic religious figures, most obviously from Christianity. But I can't think of who Perrin might represent.

**Are there official sources that explain the mythological basis for these three *ta'veren*?** I would like some sort of confirmation/correction for Mat and Rand, and an explanation for Perrin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Perrin represents blacksmiths: Vulcan/Hephaestus and Perun.

From [this interview](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=988) with Brandon Sanderson (emphasis mine):

> Oh, my question was does Perrin lose a body part in the book, since Mat has lost one, Rand has lost one, does Perrin lose one next?
>
> *Sanderson*: Perrin’s body part was the knee, where he got shot through the leg with the arrow. Because the mythological symbolism is with Mat- it’s the Odin mythology, and Odin lost an eye. **Perrin is actually the blacksmith mythology, which if you’ve read in Hephaestus and Perun and of the various blacksmiths, they usually have a bad leg.** I wasn’t going to chop off his leg. I had that wound, and he kind of feels a phantom wound, if you’ll read in the last book there are several times where his leg aches even though he was healed. That’s the symbolism there.
>
> So, did you just decide to [inaudible] or was that..?
>
> *Sanderson*: No, Robert Jordan had done that, that was him.

Sanderson also [confirmed](http://www.theoryland.com/intvmain.php?i=613) the validity of this fan speculation from [a forum thread](http://www.dragonmount.com/forums/topic/59484-perrin-and-rands-wound-foreshadowing-tom-spoilers/#entry1831859):

> The three Ta'veren from The Two Rivers all have wounds that won't heal now: Rand has lost a hand, like the Norse god Tyr, and has that Ishamael and Fain inflicted wound in his side, like Jesus. Mat has lost an eye, like Odin. And now Perrin has a wounded leg, like many mythical deities. The one that springs to mind first is the Roman God Vulcan:
>
> *"Through Vulcans identification with the Hephaestus of Greek mythology, he came to be considered as the manufacturer of art, arms, iron, jewellery and armor for various gods and heroes, including the thunderbolts of Jupiter. He was the son of Jupiter and Juno, and husband of Maia and Venus. His smithy was believed to be situated underneath Mount Etna in Sicily.*
>
> *As the son of Jupiter, the king of the gods, and Juno, the queen of the gods, Vulcan should have been quite handsome, but, baby Vulcan was small and ugly with a red, bawling face. Juno was so horrified that she hurled the tiny baby off the top of Mount Olympus.*
>
> *Vulcan fell down for a day and a night, landing in the sea. Unfortunately, one of his legs broke as he hit the water, and never developed properly."*
>
> The question arises: Was Perrin hideous as a child? :-) And for his own sake, let's not hope the authors shaped his character after the Greek blacksmith God, Hephaestus, who was lame. Well, Perrin has been lame in a number of books, but when he finally has found his stride, I hope Mr Sanderson doesn't cripple him. Some might argue that Faile already has done that deed, though :-)

Presumably the name Perrin, as well as being similar to Pippin from *Lord of the Rings* (from which Jordan, like nearly all fantasy authors, drew a lot of inspiration), came from that of **Perun**, a Slavic god. [This description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perun) sounds somewhat familiar:

> Perun is described as a rugged man with a copper beard. He [...] carries a mighty axe, or sometimes a hammer.

Comment: So Rand is supposed to represent more than just Christianity? Any chance you can elaborate on that a bit?

Comment: @MatCauthon Rand represents so much: Arthurian legend (Sword in the Stone, al'Thor ~ Arthur) and the Norse god Tyr (god of war, loses a hand) come to mind right away. I hadn't even noticed any Christian connection before.

Comment: Well, just because he's basically a messiah, and the quote you posted even says the wound in his side is similar to Jesus. Arthur and Tyr had never occurred to me, so it seems my assumptions needed some updating.

Comment: @MatCauthon Once you start looking for the Arthurian references, they're everywhere. Al'Thor with mother Tigraine, the old counsellor Merrillin, Galad the 'perfect man', Elayne, Gawyn, Morgase, Caemlyn, the Sword in the Stone, ...